# Efficient Vector Bit-Data "Rotation" / "Rearrangement" in Memory [e.g. in Python, Numpy]

Tags: python, c++, c, arrays, bit-manipulation

How does one efficiently convert from an 8 element long array of e.g. uint8s into a its "rotated" counterpart, were e.g. the original 8bits of the first element are spread across all vector elements as the MSB, and the second last element spread across the second MSB, and so on: Working and slow example:

```
import numpy as np

original = np.random.randint(0, 255, 8).astypye(np.uint8) # some random example vector
[np.binary_repr(i, width=8) for i in original]            # original data
=>['01111111',
   '00100111',
   '01110111',
   '00100010',
   '00111101',
   '10010000',
   '10000100',
   '10101000']

rotated = np.packbits(np.unpackbits(original).reshape(-1,8).T) # <= SLOW ROTATION
[np.binary_repr(i, width=8) for i in rotated]                  # this is should be the result
=>['00000111',                                                 # what where rows originally
   '10100000',                                                 # are now columns
   '11111001',
   '10101100',
   '10001001',
   '11101010',
   '11110000',
   '11101000']
```

So in the end, I want to reorder the layout how BITS are "filed" into the RAM. As you can see I got a working example in Numpy, it is not super slow (here ~ 21 µs), however I would like to do this excercise with data structures in the order of ~2k * 1 mio bits. Therefore the usage of the numpy or C bool dtype is to wasteful (factor 8 overhead).

Any C bit shuffling magic or SSE instructions or general answers are welcome!

Comment: Do you want your homework solved in python, c or c++? Or maybe you just want all three?

Comment: All you need is a decorator that redirects accesses, that way you don't have to shuffle the data at all. That said, for larger data structures, you can first rotate tiles of N by N bits by their center and then rotate them around the data structure's center. Similarly to the bit order inversion that first swaps high and low half and then inverts these.

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for the offer, but this is not homework related.

Comment: Too bad you are only allowed to add five tags. TO narrow down your question, you should add C#, Fortran, Algol and OcamML and any other PL you ever heard about.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt So for clarification, i do want to access bits, and not bytes. I cant se how one would do that efficiently with a python decorator...

Comment: @user5880052 - ok - not homework then - well, if you are looking for an easy-to-use and high performance language with good bit-operations then `c` is a good choice. Also, `c++` is just as good when used correctly. To my limited knowledge `python` will not be able to perform as well but I'm not an expert in that area. Just do a google for bitwise operators in `c` or `c++`

Comment: @4386427: As Python does not limit the size of an integer like the other languages, It would be the most simple language to use actually. Not the fastest, though. But it is not clear what OP actually wants and adding that much language tags makes it too broad.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, but C[++] or Python would be sufficient. If you care to explain how one would do it in the languarge of your choice, i would even try to understand whats going there...

Comment: @Olaf - I'm sure your right - I've seen examples of `python` code doing amazing stuff in a few lines but I assumed performance was the issue. Once again my disclaimer: I'm not a `python`expert so I could be wrong :) And most certainly agree to your comment about the question being unclear.

Comment: Will it always be 8 bit elements? Or are you looking for something more general, maybe 16, 32, and 64 bits as well? And will the  number of columns and rows always be the same?

Comment: @nabla for the example i picked a byte sized data type, the real use case would propably break down the problem in chunks of 64x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at the source provided [here](http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php)

In particular, calcperm.cpp. This is a simple bit permutation problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, kind of what i looked for, works great. Also pointed me in the direction of "8x8 bit matrix transposition", which is the keyword i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if the rotation is for a square number of rows and columns, and then it just does a transpose of the bits.

I used 8 bit elements as in the question. Also, bit 7 is the leftmost bit, while bit 0 is the rightmost bit. I'll refer to the bits in columns and rows in the following format (simply because this is how I could most quickly print the bits -- as a result the indexing is trickier than in the best case, but it can be modified appropriately):

```
    | col : 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
--------------------------
row:| 0     0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    | 1     0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
    | 2     0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    | 3     0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
    | 4     0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    | 5     0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
    | 6     1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
    | 7     1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

Then I defined the following struct to wrap the 8 bit elements, and perform the bit manipulation and printing:

```
struct Element {
    Element(uint8_t E) : e(E) {}

    // Just for convienience
    static constexpr int size = 8;
    uint8_t e;

    // Get a bit from the element
    inline uint8_t get(uint8_t i) {
        return (e >> i & 0x01);
    }

    // Flip a bit in the element
    inline void flip(uint8_t i) {
        e ^= (0x01 << i);
    }

    // Just for convienience
    void print() {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(e) << "\n";
    }
};
```

As well as the following function to flip bits in two `Element`s -- note that you only need to flip the bits if they are not the same since the elements are binary.

```
inline void swap(Element& a, Element& b, int a_offset, int b_offset) {
    if (a.get(a_offset) != b.get(b_offset)) {
        a.flip(a_offset); b.flip(b_offset);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of looping through the elements in the upper triangle (above the diagonal), and swapping them with the elements in the lower triangle (below the diagonal) as follows:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<Element> array = { 127, 39, 4, 9, 12, 100, 200, 150 };

  for (auto& a : array) a.print(); std::cout << "\n"; // Before

  // Do the swapping
  for (size_t row = 0; row < array.size(); ++row) {
    for (size_t col = Element::size - 1 - row; col >= 1; --col) {
      swap(array[row], array[Element::size - col], col - 1, Element::size - 1 - row);
    }
  }

  for (auto& a : array) a.print(); // After
}
```

Which produces the transformation as in the question : see the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dade58f1b921cf6) which shows the input and output. Compiling with `-O3` ran in about 1.1 microseconds (just the transformation, not including the printing).

You can also pretty easily change the transformation to be a 90 degree right or left rotation, just by modifying the indexing.

Comment: Thanks nabla, for the detailed example. Looks faster than my original version. If you are interested in a more theoretical aproach finding fastest possible solutions (using SSE and AVX features), calculated from the number of cpu instructions, check out @haiandbaii 's answer or search for "8x8 bit matrix inversion".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation in C for the 8x8 case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

void dump(const char *name, const byte *p, int size) {
    int len = printf("%s => ['", name) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            putchar('0' + ((p[i] >> (7 - j)) & 1));
        }
        if (i < 7) {
            printf("',\n%*s'", len, "");
        }
    }
    printf("']\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    byte original[8], rotated[8];
    int repeat = 1;

    if (argc > 1)
        repeat = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        original[i] = rand() & 255;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < repeat; r++) {
        /*-------- this is the core of the rotation --------*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            rotated[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                rotated[j] |= ((original[i] >> (7 - j)) & 1) << (7 - i);
            }
        }
        /*-------- end of the rotation code --------*/
    }
    if (repeat == 1) {
        dump("original", original, 8);
        dump("rotated", rotated, 8);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run it without an argument for a sample random test:

```
chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./rot8x8
original => ['10100111',
             '11110001',
             '11011001',
             '00101010',
             '10000010',
             '11001000',
             '11011000',
             '11111110']
rotated => ['11101111',
            '01100111',
            '11010001',
            '01100011',
            '00110111',
            '10000001',
            '10011001',
            '11100000']
```

Run it with a numeric argument for timing:

```
chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./rot8x8 20000000
real    0m0.986s
user    0m0.976s
sys     0m0.004s
```

On a MacbookPro, with `clang -O3`, this naive program performs a single rotation takes **less than 50ns**, **400 times faster** than your Numpy example.  I'm sure there are faster methods, but this is already significantly better.